# Как при остановке таймера продолжить работу с места остановки?

Tags: javascript

Делаю таймер обратного отсчета, все работает, но не знаю как реализовать продолжение отсчета с того места при клике на кнопку старт (тобото запущен таймер я нажимаю на стоп (таймер остановился) и после того нажимаю на кнопку еще раз и он продолжает отсчет с момента остановки (сейчас запускает заново))

```js
const getId = id => document.getElementById(id);

const minutes = getId('minutes');
const secondTimer = getId('secondTimer')
let timerS;
let minut = 0;

getId('plus').onclick = function () {
    if (minut <= 59) {
        minut = +minut + 1;

        if (minut < 10) minut = '0' + minut;
    }
    minutes.innerHTML = minut;
}

getId('minus').onclick = function () {

    if (minut >= 1) {
        minut = +minut - 1;

        if (minut < 10) minut = '0' + minut;
    }
    minutes.innerHTML = minut;
}

function startTimer() {
    if (!timerS) {
        countdown( "secondTimer", minutes.innerHTML, 0 );

    }
}


function resetTimer() {
   stopTimer();
   startTimer();
}

function stopTimer() {
    clearInterval(timerS);
    timerS = false;
}

function countdown(element, minutes, seconds) {
    // встановити час для конкретного відліку
    let time = minutes*60 + seconds;
        timerS = setInterval(function() {
        let el = document.getElementById(element);
        // якщо час 0, то закінчіть лічильник
        if(time == 0) {
            el.innerHTML = "End";    
            clearInterval(timerS);
            timerS = false;
            return;
        }
        let minutes = Math.floor( time / 60 );
        if (minutes < 10) minutes = "0" + minutes;
        let seconds = time % 60;
        if (seconds < 10) seconds = "0" + seconds; 
        let text = minutes + ':' + seconds;
        el.innerHTML = text;
        time--;
    }, 1000);
}
```

```html
 <div class="block">
        <div class="box">
            <div id="minutes">00</div>
            <p>MINUTES</p>
            <div class="buttons2">
                <button id="plus">+</button>
                <button id="minus">-</button>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <div id="secondTimer">00:00</div>

            <div class="buttons">
                <button onclick="startTimer()">START</button>
                <button onclick="stopTimer()">STOP</button>
                <button onclick="resetTimer()">RESET</button>
            </div>

        </div>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Как при остановке таймера продолжить работу с места остановки?

- Запустить ф-ю старт.

> Как при остановке таймера начать с начала?

- Избавиться от данных.
- Запустить ф-ю старт.

  - В которой занести в `this.data` исходные(изначальные) данные.

### пример на TypeScript

```
class Timer<T extends {}> {
    #id: number

    start() {
        if (!this.data) this.data = Object.assign(Object.create(null), this.initData)
        if (!this.#id) this.#id = this.gen()
    }
    stop() {
        clearInterval(this.#id)
        this.#id = undefined
        this.data = undefined
    }
    pause() {
        clearInterval(this.#id)
        this.#id = undefined
    }

    data: T
    gen(): number {
        return setInterval(() => {
            this.foo(this.data)
        }, this.step)
    }

    constructor(
        private initData: T,
        private foo: (data: T) => void,
        private step: number = 1e3
    ) { }
}


test: {
    const t = new Timer({ counter: 0 }, data => {
        data.counter++
        console.log(data.counter)
    })
    test()
    function test() {
        t.start()
        setTimeout(() => {
            t.pause()
            setTimeout(() => {
                t.start()
                setTimeout(() => {
                    t.stop()
                    test()
                }, 3e3)
            }, 3e3)
        }, 5e3)
    }
}
```

#### P.S.

1e3 = 1000 -> 1 секунда

[там песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?strictNullChecks=false&allowUnusedLabels=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=53&pc=2#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCWBbApgJwDy2sgHgF2QDsATGAbwF8A%20aMgKGkegGJ5iAuaQgV0QCM0dBkwh4wqPAAoAlLWFMm8AGbRJAQjwALeBAB0xMGNlad%20w2GgBeaAHk%20AK2TA8uyBHgBzQpLuPnu4FRkQ2RJHhAQaQAaaBM9eEJ4PAARc2l5BWhlVQ1tPVZiYzzdAqtY4o8iGQyKDNEAewAHGTlMplBg1ABJQgJUADcwEEk4krZ0tsZRgzEy7hJkJQTkYgyFUdLreeJF5dWFWoVGsG4IUNl6SegO8R6%20weGN8bWmJ%20I5haXCFZqhBRmwJxYBlKt5pJwePw0K1JkE8NxUIRoGc8Hc0A9JC1LDRLldXsUlPV6iNigCJpMKDFRqJkI1yYxahlgPVCKJUNxnPVUJIXoxGqh4IMCFlEilzECorzoPzBSFoIT6pxJACgbJsdB%20vU2JKrjKhchkQRGhDeAJUGUAIzIADMGQu0FqjLoBFEnFxjGZrLwsTK3wA7nAkGhJGRrvV5n1OAAGB0xAFWHFSgEBcO9NAAanTUs9EHqIGQuhA9Q8yvMKYjaHpDqrLqkVaU82c8BZsWQoha7syLlE4jrUpRCBQ4akWMTeNeumOp3OUoUA6Dw8xarH467uh7Emqq8y86H3BHy5h27a3bwTS3x5Pbb7l4ZMWtNqrV0p0Af1qfTBfAFZH39P3QKCAA)

### UPD: добавил пример(TS) на ф-ях

```
function Timer<T extends {}>(initData: T) {

    let id: number | undefined
    let data: T | undefined

    return (
        foo: (data: T) => void,
        step: number = 1e3
    ) => ({
        initData, foo, step
        , start() {
            if (!data) data = Object.assign(Object.create(null), this.initData)
            if (!id) id = this.gen()
        }
        , stop() {
            clearInterval(id)
            id = undefined
            data = undefined
        }
        , pause() {
            clearInterval(id)
            id = undefined
        }
        , gen(): number {
            return setInterval(() => {
                this.foo(data as any)
            }, this.step)
        }
    })
}

test: {
    const t = Timer({ counter: 0 })(data => {
        data.counter++
        console.log(data.counter)
    })
    test()
    function test() {
        t.start()
        setTimeout(() => {
            t.pause()
            setTimeout(() => {
                t.start()
                setTimeout(() => {
                    t.stop()
                    test()
                }, 3e3)
            }, 3e3)
        }, 5e3)
    }
}
```

### [javascript deep clone](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20deep%20clone)

```
data = Object.assign(Object.create(null), this.initData)
```

```
data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.initData))
```

```
// ...
```

Comment: непонятный пример для меня, но спасибо за помощь (не учил еще классы и тд)

Comment: @Roma, перейди по ссылке в самом низу, может понятнее будет.

Comment: @Roma, добавил пример на ф-ях. поможет ли